# c# windows service use HKEY_USERS current logged user

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0

I have a windows service running as LocalSystem and i need to access a regedit from the current user logged. I try work around using:
**System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name** -> that returns a profile of System (S-1-5-18) and i need is "S-1-5-21-2238971182-363666278-428364487-1001";
**Environment.UserName** it returns "System"
I also use CurrentUser but is the same.^
How i access a regestry key used by System but with the current logged use SID

Comment: Windows has supported multiple logged-in users since Fast User Switching was added to Windows XP. There is no concept of a single logged-in user. What are you trying to do?

Comment: My goal is access a regestry is located in HKEY_USERS\{sid}\SOFTWARE\. to do that I need know a SID of user logged in the machine

Comment: **There is no concept of a single logged-in user.** Would enumerating the SIDs of the currently-logged-in **users** suffice?

Comment: How i get that list? my problem is the current SID is different that i expect

Comment: "the current SID" is *your* SID, i.e. that of your service, because it's running in that context. "How i get that list?" ... if that's what you want, ask _that_ question.

Comment: How i get that list?

Comment: You edit this question (or close it and ask a new one) that actually asks the question you want answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in windows at once can be multiple logged-in users. so need some condition, based on which you select "current". for example you can call [`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use this *SessionId* in call [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx). alternatively you can enumerate all currently logged users by [`WTSEnumerateSessions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833(v=vs.85).aspx) and for each call [`WTSQueryUserToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840(v=vs.85).aspx)

after you got user token (this will be *`TokenPrimary`* [`TOKEN_TYPE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379633(v=vs.85).aspx)), you can query it [`TokenUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx) for get user *SID* and then use this *SID* for open `HKEY_USERS\{sid}` key (this is most effective). or call [`DuplicateToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446616(v=vs.85).aspx) for get *`TokenImpersonation`*, [`SetThreadToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`RegOpenCurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724894(v=vs.85).aspx) (after this again call `SetThreadToken(0,0)` for reset impersonation) - but this is of course much less effective then first way.